# How to expand vectors or arrays in variadic parameter pack?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I would like to expand an array or a vector in a variadic template pack.
Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
int GetArgValue(std::string name,T& value){
   cout<<"GetArgumentValue(): name="<<name<<", val="<<value<<endl;
   //Set value
   //...                        
   return 0;
}

template<typename ... Tn>
int GetArgValues(std::vector<std::string> keys, Tn&... values){
  //Check sizes
  //...

  //Call GetArg over pack
  int retCodes[] = { GetArgValue(keys,values)...};//not possible

  //...
  return 0; 
}
```

Is it possible to expand arrays or vectors together with the pack? If not what would be a suitable approach for this use case?
What I would like to achieve at the end is the following:

```
double arg1;
int arg2;
std::string arg3;
GetArgValues({"firstArg","secondArg","thirdArg"},arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

or even better (if possible):

```
GetArgValues( {"firstArg",arg1}, {"secondArg",arg2}, {"thirdArg", arg3} );
```

Hope that the example is clear. 
Thanks all for suggestions.

Comment: #1 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0f1aec11b820582

Comment: `{"firstArg", arg1}` is not a deduced type, `std::make_pair("firstArg", arg1)` would be an option [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7aed99507f9aaa4). (an other alternative would be: `GetArgValues( "firstArg", arg1, "secondArg", arg2, "thirdArg", arg3);`)

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1a68f2b8431ac8c) for the last alternative.

Comment: You want to convert the strings to the typed arguments?

Comment: @Galik: No need to convert strings. String args are used internally as keys to find an argument object from a list.

Comment: @Jarod: Last alternative works fine. I cannot have C++14 features in the project, so I can not explore at the moment the other nice options suggested.

Comment: @Jarod: I will check the map option demo as well. It would be nice to have some shortcut for the "make_pair". Is it fine with macros?

Comment: You may create a function instead of macro, `template <typename T1, typename T2>auto p(T1&& t1, T2&&t2) { std::make_pair(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2)); }`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::index_sequence` for this. Note that this is C++14, but there are plenty of implementations around for C++11 if needs be.

We make a helper function which will receive a compile-time-generated sequence of indices to access the vector with:

```
template<typename ... Tn, std::size_t...  Idx>
int GetArgValuesHelp(std::index_sequence<Idx...>,
                     std::vector<std::string> keys,
                     Tn&... values){
  int retCodes[] = { GetArgValue(keys[Idx],values)...};

  return 0; 
}
```

Then call that function and generate the indices from `GetArgValues`:

```
template<typename ... Tn>
int GetArgValues(std::vector<std::string> keys, Tn&... values){
  //Check sizes
  //...

  return GetArgValuesHelp(std::index_sequence_for<Tn...>{}, keys, values...);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e80262ec53cf695d)